# Making edge loops flat

Tags: edges, topology

[image: Weird edge loop]

I was following a tutorial and I had to extrude the character's arms but the edge loop wasn't flat and the Instructor flattened the edge loop by scaling it on y by 0. I tried doing the same but it doesn't work and intuitively doesn't make sense. Basically I'm looking for how to make a edge loop look like it's parallel to a plane

Comment: Hello, please show some pictures of your problem, it will help to understand

Comment: I found the solution in a different tutorial and quite frankly, it was a stupid but I'll edit some pictures in my question so that hopefully you'll be able to understand it.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Flattened edge loop]

Instead of scaling the loop in the properties menu, just press s to scale, z to scale it along z and then type zero. This will make the edge loop flat in xy axis.

Comment: A one-click alternative to the "scaling to zero" trick is to load the Loop Tools addon (which comes with Blender by default but is not active by default). It has a button called "Flatten" which does the same thing. It's only faster than scaling to zero if you have the tool active and open at the moment, however. But it also has some other interesting features, and at any rate, having all the Loop Tools features available at all times while modeling is vastly more handy than not having them all available. So I recommend it.